# Difficult vs difficulty

Tags: word-choice

Do we say: One of the symptoms may be "difficult breathing" or "difficulty breathing"? Can the word difficulty be used as a modifier? Thanks for help. Jakub

Comment: *Jakub has difficulty breathing.* is well-formed and grammatical, idiomatic even.  It means the same as *Jakub finds breathing difficult.*. Personally I don't find *difficulty* to be a modifier of *breathing*, rather that *breathing* clarifies the *difficulty* Jakub has.  One couldn't drop *difficulty* from the first sentence, as modifiers often can be dropped, it would leave the oddity *Jakub has breathing.*

Comment: We _do_ say "He has difficulty breathing" as a shortened form of "He has difficulty in breathing", but 'difficulty breathing' as a bare string looks an unlikely deletion. And "One of the symptoms may be difficulty breathing" would be better "One of the symptoms may be difficulty in breathing". // While 'difficult breathing' _is_ a valid phrase, "One of the symptoms may be difficult breathing" is again less idiomatic than "One of the symptoms may be difficulty in breathing", ...

Comment: as [these Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=may+be+difficult+breathing%2Cmay+be+difficulty+in+breathing&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmay%20be%20difficulty%20in%20breathing%3B%2Cc0) suggest (though the former may well be gaining ground). [Corrected; first submitted as first comments ... this will kibosh relative timings (+ 40 min say).]

Comment: @EdwinAshworth How interesting! I would have said "difficulty with breathing" but Google ngrams shows "difficulty in breathing" used over 10 times as much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would say "She is having difficulty breathing", or "It is difficult to breathe".

Answer (score 8):

No, *difficulty* cannot be used as a modifier, except in rare cases like *your difficulty count*, which is an unusual but possible alternative to *the count of your difficulties*.

As others have pointed out, your sentence does not contain a component *difficulty breathing*: the two words are separate in the sentence structure. :

> You [have difficulty] [breathing].

Comment: Now it's clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Difficult** = *something that is difficult*

**Difficulty** = *The "ability" or "state" of something that is being considered to be difficult ("demanding") due to the fact that requires some special prerequisites/requirements to be met*.